# How do I produce the correct Cohen's d estimate?

Tags: statistics, t-test

I am trying to replicate the result of an academic paper below to practice how to apply statistical methods in R.

This is what the paper states:

> **Pre- and postoutbreak differences in voter intentions.**
>   Across the 32 elections included in primary analyses, the mean voter-intention difference score was greater than zero (*M*=1.02%), *d*=0.84, *t*(31)=2.34, *p*=.026.
>   This result is consistent with the pre- and postelection difference in nationwide polling results for the House of Representatives elections, which indicates a general postoutbreak shift toward favoring Republican rather than Democratic candidates. (If the two outliers were
>   included in the analysis, the mean voter-intention difference score was not meaningfully different from zero, *p*=.937.) ([Source screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkjXf.png))

The t-test result matched the values in the paper, however, I cannot figure out how to produce the right cohen's d estimate. I looked into the documentation for `cohen.d` function over and over again, googled how to do this, even watched some boring Youtube videos, but to no avail. The code itself runs, but it gives me a wrong value. Am I missing something? Can someone help me with how I should format the arguments?

```
# excluding outliers from the dataset
no_outliers <- study2 %>%
  filter(StateSenateRace != "Rhode Island", StateSenateRace != "Hawaii")

# paired t-test
t.test(no_outliers$OctMeanVoterIntentionIndex, no_outliers$SeptMeanVoterIntentionIndex, paired = TRUE, var.equal = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

cohen.d(no_outliers$SeptMeanVoterIntentionIndex, no_outliers$OctMeanVoterIntentionIndex, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Here's the result I got.

```
Cohen's d

d estimate: -0.02130406 (negligible)
95 percent confidence interval:
     lower      upper 
-0.5171041  0.4744960
```

Thank you in advance--I wish I could contribute to Stack Overflow as a R expert someday!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I converted your screenshot, and did some other minor edits, hope that's ok.